# Problems deserializing a pointer to a derived class using Boost:serialize

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have a weird problem trying to deserialize a pointer to a derived class with boost serialize. I have a base and derived with save/load function outside them (non intrusive version) but each time I try to deserialize a pointer I get either "Input Stream Error" exception or "Unregistered class" exception. Here is what I do:

First I define my classes:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/archive_exception.hpp>
#include "boost/serialization/split_free.hpp"
#include "boost/serialization/export.hpp"
#include "boost/serialization/utility.hpp"
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>

class Base
{
public:
    bool isEnabled;
    Base();
    virtual ~Base(){}
};
Base::Base()
{
    isEnabled = 0;
}

class Derived : public Base
{

public:
    Derived();
    virtual ~Derived(){}
    int layerHeight;
};
Derived::Derived():Base()
{}
```

Then I make sure their traits are what I need:

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Base, "Base")
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(Base)
BOOST_CLASS_IS_WRAPPER(Base)
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(Base, boost::serialization::track_selectively)
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(Base, boost::serialization::object_class_info)

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(Derived)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Derived, "Derived")
BOOST_CLASS_IS_WRAPPER(Derived)
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(Derived, boost::serialization::object_class_info)
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(Derived, boost::serialization::track_selectively)
```

Next I define actual save/load functions:

```
namespace boost {

    namespace serialization {

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar,const Base& obj, const unsigned int version)
    {
        bool isEnabled = obj.isEnabled;
        ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(isEnabled);
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, Base& obj, const unsigned int version)
    {
        bool isEnabled;
        ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(isEnabled);
    }
    } // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost

namespace boost {
template<>
struct is_virtual_base_of<Base, Derived>: public mpl::true_ {};

namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & ar,const Derived& obj, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(obj);
    int height =obj.layerHeight;
    ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(height);
}
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, Derived& obj, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar.template register_type<Base>();
    ar.template register_type<Derived>();
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(obj);
    int height;
    ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(height);
}
} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

And 2 save/load helpers I borrowed from Docs

```
template <typename T>
void save_schedule(const T& s, const char * filename){
    // make an archive
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    assert(ofs.good());
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(s);
}

template <typename T>
void restore_schedule(T &s, const char * filename)
{
    // open the archive
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    assert(ifs.good());
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(ifs);
    // restore the schedule from the archive
    ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(s);
}
```

Finally - here is how I try to use it all

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Base* basePointer = new Base();
    Base* objectPointer = new Derived();
    Derived * secondObjectPointer = new Derived();
    Derived justObject;

    save_schedule(basePointer, "C:\\basePointer.xml");
    save_schedule(objectPointer, "C:\\objectPointer.xml");
    save_schedule(secondObjectPointer , "C:\\secondObjectPointer.xml");
    save_schedule(justObject, "C:\\justObject.xml");

    //this works OK
    restore_schedule(basePointer, "C:\\basePointer.xml");

    //this gives "Input Stream Error"
    restore_schedule(objectPointer, "C:\\objectPointer.xml");

    //this gives "Unregistered class"
    restore_schedule(secondObjectPointer, "C:\\secondObjectPointer.xml");

    //This works >__< But I need to serialize pointers so I cannot use this
    restore_schedule(justObject, "C:\\justObject.xml");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I deserialize anything other than a pointer to a base class?

Comment: If you solved your problem, post the solution as an _answer_.

Comment: For that, I will need to find HOW to do this :)  Sorry, I am completely new. P.S. It seems like I won't be able to post it as an answer for the next 4 hours - site restriction

Comment: Then it's not the solution after all? You said the problem was solved.

Comment: It is the solution, I just was not sure how to post anything as an answer instead of editing my post and now it turns out there is 8hrs restriction on that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misinterpreted your initial comment. You meant you don't know how to post an answer on SO; I thought you were talking about implementing your solution. Yes, you must wait 8 hours before posting a self-answer; still, please _do that_. I've taken your solution off the question as it does not belong there. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPD:: After some more searching I was able to trace my problem to this answer:**

[boost serialization exception: unregistered class, serializing polymorphic base problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432019/boost-serialization-exception-unregistered-class-serializing-polymorphic-base)

replacing

```
//original taken from Boost Docs
ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(obj);
```

with

```
// taken from the link above (macro expanded)
ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp( BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(obj),boost::serialization::base_object<Base >(obj));
```

does solve the issue.

As a side note - **I've found another type of weird error that can arise and cause "stream input error"**. It works like this:

If there is even ONE constructor in your hierarchy that CAN initialize a variable (any variable) but doesn't - you will get stream input error trying to deserialize.

If there are no variables in a class - all is OK. But if there is even one - you MUST initialize at least one variable in the constructor of that class! I have no idea why is this important but this solved a major issue for me.

Comment: Actually, I'd very much like to hear an explanation what happens when I do not initialize anything in the constructor of a base class. I mean - I still call it explicitly with :Base() ... does it get optimized out or anything since there is nothing to perform in it?

Comment: Boost is powerful, but.. eh. I've spent the last 2 hours trying to serialize a derived class. Reading the tutorial/book did no good. Your post solved my compile error. Still no idea **why even the official tutorials dont manage to show proper usage of this library**

Comment: Actually, this question(boost having no useful examles/forgetting to mention important things) is a recurring one. I get this close to every time I try to use something new from boost >_< Still... it's powerful enough for me to stumble again and again because I just know it's worth it :)

Comment: Did you find an actual **reason**, why boost requires you to initialize a field?

Comment: Nope. Not that I had the time to research seriously. Ppl at freenode #boost guessed that it is not impossible and probably has to do with some template stuff boost does behind the curtains. At the time - I was just happy that it worked ... :)

Comment: @Zeks I wrote a small test program having a couple of classes with constructors that do not initialize class variables. And it works.

Comment: Are you sure you tried it with class hierarchies? Can you post your test code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert of Boost Serialization. I experience with it only for two days. I got the same problem than yours and after reading the complete documentation, I still didn't succeed in fixing the problem. But your solution, which works for me, makes me think of the following.

As the documentation explains in the chapter [Special Considerations/XML Archives](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#xml_archives):

> XML differs from other formats in that it requires a name for
>   each data member. Our goal is to add this information to the class
>   serialization specification while still permitting the 
>   serialization code to be used with any archive. This is achieved by
>   requiring that all data serialized to an XML archive be serialized as
>   a name-value pair.

That means each field must be saved with a name when using XML archive. This is why we always need to use `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP` macro which adds a stringified conversion of the argument's name in the XML file.

Your solution makes me think that even for the serialization of the base class, XML requires a name associated to it. `boost::serialization::base_object<Base>` can't provide an automatic name as `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP` does, so we would need to provide it explicitly with the function:

```
template<class T> const nvp< T > boost::serialization::make_nvp(const char * name, T & t)
```

`BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(obj)` stringifies the argument `obj`. In my case, I prefer to give a string litteral:

```
ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("MyBase", boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(obj));
```

That is my understanding. Please correct me if I am false.