# deserialization from an abstract base fails for boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, polymorphism, deserialization

I'm able to serialize an object through an abstract base using boost::serialization. However, when I try to add deserialization, I get compile errors about the abstract base. Here's my serialization code that works:

```
/*
    g++ -Iinclude/ -Llib -lboost_serialization ~/Desktop/ser_ex.cpp -o stest
*/

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <memory>

namespace bser = boost::serialization;
using namespace std;
namespace foo {
class AA
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~AA() {}
    std::string name;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned int )
    {
        ar & name;
    }
};
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT( AA );

class BB : public AA
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    virtual ~BB () {}
    int thing;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned int )
    {
        ar.template register_type< AA >();
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<AA>(*this);
        ar & thing;
    }
};
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT( BB );

class CC : public BB
{
public:
    virtual void foo() {}
    virtual void bar() {}
    virtual ~CC() {}
    int otherThing;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned int )
    {
        ar.template register_type< BB >();
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<BB>(*this);
        ar & otherThing;
    }
};
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(foo::CC)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(foo::CC)


int main (int , char const **)
{
    std::vector< shared_ptr<foo::AA> > vv;
    vv.push_back( make_shared<foo::CC>() );

    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive out_archive( oss );
    out_archive << vv;
    std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Just add this line right below the include for binary_oarchive.hpp causes the code not to compile.

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
```

```
dawilcox-macOS:debug dawilcox$ make foo
dependencies: foo_main.o
building: foo_main.o
In file included from /Users/dawilcox/src/axle/foo_main.cpp:5:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:43:
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:17: error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'foo::AA'
        ::new(t)T;
```

Boost is complaining that it can't instantiate my base type. That's kind of the point -- it's an abstract base type.

What's the proper way to deserialize an abstract base?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library but conceptually you can't deserialize an abstract base. Deserializing implies creating an instance which is not possible for an abstract type. You would need to deserialize to an actual derived type. Maybe you mean to deserialize the base portion of a derived type though, which is fine in the context of deserializing a derived type.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I've seen a lot of notes in the docs that you need to deserialize into the same class that you serialize from. There's also quite a bit of mentioning of abstract classes in the docs along with some macros about abstract (see the macro I'm using above for this). For those reasons, I'd be a bit surprised if this wasn't supported by boost. It's all a bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the thing I have wrong is that I was registering against the base class in the deserialize function. So, I got rid of:

```
 ar.template register_type< AA >();
```

and changed

```
ar.template register_type< BB >();
```

to

```
ar.template register_type< CC >();
```

Here's my full code:

```
/*
    g++ -Iinclude/ -Llib -lboost_serialization ~/Desktop/ser_ex.cpp -o stest
*/

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <OMNIMAKE/lib/boost_serialization>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <memory>

namespace bser = boost::serialization;
using namespace std;
namespace foo {
class AA
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~AA() {}
    std::string name;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned int )
    {
        ar & name;
    }
};
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT( AA );

class BB : public AA
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    virtual ~BB () {}
    int thing;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned int )
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<AA>(*this);
        ar & thing;
    }
};
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT( BB );

class CC : public BB
{
public:
    virtual void foo() {}
    virtual void bar() {}
    virtual ~CC() {}
    int otherThing;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned int )
    {
        ar.template register_type< CC >();
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<BB>(*this);
        ar & otherThing;
    }
};
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(foo::CC)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(foo::CC)


int main (int , char const **)
{
    std::vector< shared_ptr<foo::AA> > vv;
    vv.push_back( make_shared<foo::CC>() );

    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive out_archive( oss );
    out_archive << vv;
    std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
}
```